# Pytest and rounding floats in namedtuples

Tags: python, pytest, namedtuple

If two named tuples are equal, they can be asserted in pytest like this:

```
assert tuple_under_test == expected_tuple
```

I want to do the same for named tuples containing floats. The catch is that these float values need to be rounded for proper comparison. Is there something similar to `pytest.approx` for named tuples?

```
assert tuple_under_test == compare_approx(Tuple(
    FloatValue=2.2
    FloatValue=2.3
), rel=0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out that it is possible to use pytest.approx for named tuples as well. So this just works as exptected:

```
assert tuple_under_test == pytest.approx(Tuple(
    FloatValue=2.2
    FloatValue=2.3
), rel=0.1)
```

Great ;-)